# Shrinking a String to substrings

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android and working on a project, and in a part of that I need to shrink a string to smaller substrings.

For example let's assume the string is "A-87B9C143D24E940|jOmbFACBBAAAAADB2" and length of this string is not fixed.
The thing I want is that put characters from A to B to a string variable (like S0 = 87), from B to C to another one (like S1 = 9) from D to E to another one (like S3 = 143) from E to | to another one (like S4 = 940) and everything after | goes to another substring (like S5 = jOmbFACBBAAAAADB2);

Comment: `String.substring()` probably could help you. Also is count of substring fixed?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you done any research like reading the documentation for the `String` class? Using the right methods in the String class this should not be too complicated.

Comment: Okay,we can do it logically, But will always have A,B,C,D and E in String right?

Comment: what happened to the minus sign between  `A` and `8` (second character of string)? An just an example is a very *restricted* specification (like missing what happens if there is no `B`  or if `D` comes first, or ..., or ..., ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to know the position of the char to split or what chars to split, you simply apply the same in a substring (substring takes the index of the chat if you know it, if not, you use the indexOf to get the index of the given char as below):

```
String aString = "A-87B9C143D24E940|jOmbFACBBAAAAADB2";
String S0 = aString.substring((aString.indexOf("A")+1), aString.indexOf("B"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //include A in resultant string
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('A'), s.indexOf('B')));
    //exclode A from resultant string
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('A') + 1, s.indexOf('B')));
```

you must have got the basic idea now.